# flutter can't access static variable

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, static, flutter-onpressed

I want to access a static variable in a stateful widget in a flutter.
but it does not work.
and someone said that is a private widget and I can't access it.
so how can I access the variable `isCollapsed` in the below code:

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final int activeTabIndex;

  const BottomNavBar({Key? key, required this.activeTabIndex})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
    static var isCollapsed = false;
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 Scaffold(
        body: SlidingUpPanel(
          controller: _pc,
          panelBuilder: (sc) {
            if (isCollapsed == false) _pc.hide();
            if (isCollapsed == true) _pc.show();
            return Container(
              child: Center(child: Text("Panel")),
            );
          },
          body: Text("something");
        ),  }
}
```

I want to change isCollapsed in another class,
when clicked on the icon, isCollapsed changes to true.

```
class _PlayerPreviewState extends State<PlayerPreview> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String play = 'assets/icons/play.svg';
    var pageWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return  Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: pageWidth * .04),
        child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
                               
         },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(play),
                            ),
                          );}}
```

can anyone help me please how can I do it?

Comment: you should use changeNotifier Provider to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `_BottomNavBarState` is private because it starts with  underscore`_`. if you want to make it public, remove `_` from name and it will be like

```dart
  @override
  BottomNavBarState createState() => BottomNavBarState();
}

class BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  static var isCollapsed = false;
```

and use anywhere like `BottomNavBarState.isCollapsed`, but I should prefer **state-management** while the variable has effects on state.

For more about

- [state-management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)
- [dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

Comment: can i use this? `BottomNavBarState.isCollapsed == true;`

Comment: thanks for sharing links.actually i dont know about state-management very well

Comment: i use this : `onPressed: () {                                BottomNavBarState.isCollapsed = true;},` but its nor working actually.

Comment: Because we aren't updating the state, and yes it just changes the value, that's why we need to handle the state, using `setState()` may help, consider learning about state-management like `setState` ,`provider`,`riverpod`,`bloc`+....... check that link you will get it.